# Combinatorics optimization problem: combine 1D arrays of size 4 such that their sum does not exceed [200,200,200,200]. Minimize no. of combinations.

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, discrete-optimization

I would need some help. Please forgive my lack of mathematical annotations.

**Problem:** I have a large set of 1D-arrays of size 4 and value range [0, 200]. E.g.: [0, 10, 83, 92], [20, 180, 10, 100], [1, 0, 9, 2], [150, 20, 30, 20], etc.
I would like to combine/group these arrays such that the addition of the arrays in one group does not exceed [200, 200, 200, 200]. Furthermore, the number of groups should be minimized, making it a combinatorics and optimization problem.

**Example:** E.g. one group can contain [50, 50, 50, 50] + [50, 50, 50, 50] + [100, 100, 100, 100] <= [200, 200, 200, 200], but not [180, 180, 180, 180] + [100, 100, 100, 100] > 200.

**Tools:** I work with Python and am trying to prevent using optimizers such as scipy.optimize. Maybe there is one single solution?

Please ask questions if anything remains unclear. Thank you in advance and kind regards.

Comment: Please type a title that is *informative* and relates to the content of your question.  Also, show your work.

Comment: HI, I cannot share my work since it's a very large Python script. But my example describes the problem very well. I will change the title. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: this is a generalization of [bin packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem)

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you for this keyword. Will make sure to find an adequate solver.

Comment: One problem however still remains: I have an array of arrays and not simply an array of values. This isn't compatible with the algorithms that already exist (e.g. the Python "binpacking" package).

Comment: Indeed, it is *multidimensional bin packing*.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will use a heuristic approach, using the "best fit algorithm", which seems very straightforward. At one step an item is packed into the bin that leads to the smallest residual. I will have to think about a strategy for calculating residuals in 1D-arrays. Maybe I will use the mean residual from all 8 entries in one 1D-array, or I will pick the entry out of all 8 with the lowest residual.